# ¿Cómo alterar la base de datos a un tablespace por defecto sin afectar los usuarios existentes en Oracle 11g?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Estoy elaborando un inventario de base de datos y estandarizando algunas tareas de administración, entre ellas la creación de usuarios. Quisiera que al crear un usuario se le asigne por defecto el tablespace `USERS`. Bien, encontré la siguiente sentencia para establecer un tablespace por defecto en una base de datos:

```
ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS;
```

Después de la ejecución noté que, aparte de alterar la base también movió algunos usuarios del sistema a dicho tablespace (`USERS`), entre ellos al usuario `XS$NULL`, lo que no sabía era que este usurio era muy especial, puesto que, al intentar mover dichos usuarios a su tablespace de origen (`SYSTEM`), pude hacerlos con todos menos con `XS$NULL`, y me mostró el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
ALTER USER XS$NULL DEFAULT TABLESPACE SYSTEM
Informe de error -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

La documentación resumió que no se podía hacer nada, incluso estando como `SYSDBA`. Por lo que, no me quedó más opción que regresar la base de datos a su valor original:

```
ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT TABLESPACE SYSTEM;
```

Como era de esperarse, esto movió todos los usuarios al tablespace `SYSTEM`, incluyendo el usuario `HR`, que se encontraba originalmente en el tablespace `USERS`, aunque este si fue fácil de devolverlo a su lugar.

El tema es que quisiera saber si hay algún modo de modificar el tablespace por defecto sin tener que afectar a otros usuarios.

*Algunas consideraciones adicionales:*

- Las ejecuciones se realizaron con el usuario `SYS`.
- Solo se alteraron usuarios provenientes del tablespace `SYSTEM`.
- No se alteraron todos los usuarios del tablespace SYSTEM (`SYS`, `SYSTEM` y `OUTLN`).

Comment: La creación de usuarios es por algún aplicativo? Podría usar PL/SQL creando un package que se encargue de la administración de usuarios, y así garantizar que el tablespace defatult sea el deseado usando SQL dinámico.

Comment: ¿Me podrías dar una idea de cómo crear ese package como alternativa para solucinar este inconveniente?